Add links between traces via AWS XRay API (or SDK)
Context
We have an application composed of many Lambda functions connected via EventBridge and X-Ray has worked great so far. Recently, we added an ECS Fargate container running on NodeJS which is proving to be a pain to instrument with the X-Ray SDK.
The problem (among many others) I'm currently trying to solve is that I would like the calls made by the ECS container to other AWS services/instrumented apps to appear as a separate trace in the trace graph. Currently the API call is shown as a subsegment of the trace of the Lambda.
In case it is relevant, all our code is in Typescript.
Lambda code:
import { captureFetchGlobal } from '/opt/nodejs/aws-utils/xray';

const fetchWrapper = captureFetchGlobal(true);
const response = await fetchWrapper(requestUrl, {
  keepalive: true,
  signal: timeout ? AbortSignal.timeout(timeout) : undefined,
  method,
  body: method === 'GET' ? null : requestBody,
  headers: { ...headers, 'Content-Type': contentType },
});


Server code:
import fastify from 'fastify';
import AWSXRay from 'aws-xray-sdk-core';
import { setupFastify } from './app';

export const server = fastify(
  {
    logger: true,
  },
);

AWSXRay.setContextMissingStrategy('IGNORE_ERROR');

server.register(require('fastify-xray'), {
  defaultName: 'livechat-service',
  AWSXRay,
});

// Run the server!
export const start = async () => {
  const { PORT = '80' } = process.env;
  try {
    await setupFastify(server);
    await server.listen({ port: parseInt(PORT!, 10), host: '0.0.0.0' });
  } catch (err) {
    server.log.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

The result is the following trace graph:

Investigation
I believe, based on the available methods and backed by this open issue that the SDK does not support links, but happy to be told otherwise.
Looking into the raw data through X-Ray it appears that Segments have an optional field links, however, as far as I can tell, this field is not documented in the API specs.
Question
I was wondering if there was a way to add links between traces using the XRay API. Is it as simple as using this undocumented field? Does anyone have a better suggestion?
Notes
I'm aware that it might be easier to solve this using subsegments for external calls and simply accepting that the trace graph will show everything within the trace of the lambda. If there is no other solution I will take this route.
